# Polymer Automatic Node Finding Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, shadow-dom

I'm using [Polymer Web Components](https://www.polymer-project.org/).

**Whenever I use [`this.$`](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#automatic-node-finding) I get an error that it is undefined.** I also tried `this.shadowRoot` and it states that it is null.

For example:

Inside a `<polymer-element>`:

```
<script>
    Polymer({
        cardClick: function(event, detail, sender) {
            this.$.ordertemplatediv.style.display = 'none';
               // the above line gives the following error:
               //   "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined"

            this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#ordertemplatediv').style.display = 'none';
               // the above line gives the following error:
               //   "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null"
        }
    });
</script>
```

Inside another `<polymer-element>` in another file: *(closing tags were omitted for clarity)*

```
<template>
    <div id="ordertemplatediv">
        <template repeat="{{item in items}}">
            <!-- some irrelevant elements -->
```

Both files' root element is `<polymer-element>`.

I tried using `this.$` many times in different situations in this project but it never worked. Any ideas?

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1 - CONTEXT**

This is what I actually want to do:

I have 3 `<polymer-elements>` which we will call `<list-1>`, `<l-card>` and `<list-2>`.

`<list-1>` looks something like this: *(closing tags were omitted for clarity)*

```
<polymer-element name="list-1">
    <template>
        <template repeat="{{post in posts}}">
            <l-card>
```

`<l-card>` contains the `<script>` above.

`<list-2>` contains the `<template>` above.

**I want `<list-2>` to be refreshed (data reloaded) when an `<l-card>` in `<list-2>` is clicked (or tapped).**

Answer (score 1):

If you're separating the `Polymer()` call and the `<polymer-element>` it registers, you'll need to pass the name of the element:

```
Polymer('your-element', {
   ...
});
```

Otherwise, you'll need to put the `<template>` inside the `<polymer-element>` so the nameless registration works.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Let's say the first `<polymer-element>`'s name is `element-1` and the second one's name is `element-2` (from question above). If I write `Polymer('element-1', { ... });` instead of the `Polymer({ ... });` above nothing changes (same errors). If I write `Polymer('element-2', { ... });`, it gives an error saying that the prototype is already registered (in `element-2` I already have `Polymer('element-2', { ... });` Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but you're not going to be able to do this. If `<div id="ordertemplatediv">` is in another element definition (element-1), `this.$.ordertemplatediv` in element-2 won't exist.

Comment: Do you have an idea how to solve this? I updated my question with the actual problem.